# Python selenium multithreading, "separate WebDriver instance"

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium-webdriver, thread-safety

I am confused what they mean by **"separate WebDriver instance"** to make it **Thread Safe**, does this mean for each thread in my code I will use different webdriver?

for example if I have 3 threads that means I will have to add 3 different webdrive to my project to use each one of them separately is that true?

Here is what people say is thread safe, which is I am confused why:

```
import threading
from selenium import webdriver

def thread_function():
    # Initialize a new WebDriver instance for this thread
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    
    # Perform actions with this WebDriver instance
    driver.get("https://www.example.com")
    # ...

    # Close the WebDriver instance when done
    driver.quit()

# Create multiple threads, each with its WebDriver
thread1 = threading.Thread(target=thread_function)
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=thread_function)

# Start the threads
thread1.start()
thread2.start()

# Wait for threads to complete
thread1.join()
thread2.join()
```

and here is what I am trying to do, am I doing it correctly?

```
import threading
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

# Define a function for the first thread
def thread_one():
    # Initialize the WebDriver instance for the first thread
    driver1 = webdriver.Chrome()
    
    # Navigate to a website and interact with it
    driver1.get("https://www.example.com")
    search_box = driver1.find_element_by_name("q")
    search_box.send_keys("Example")
    search_box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    
    # Close the browser for the first thread
    driver1.quit()

# Define a function for the second thread
def thread_two():
    # Initialize the WebDriver instance for the second thread
    driver2 = webdriver.Chrome()
    
    # Navigate to a different website and interact with it
    driver2.get("https://www.example.org")
    link = driver2.find_element_by_link_text("Link")
    link.click()
    
    # Close the browser for the second thread
    driver2.quit()

# Create two threads
thread1 = threading.Thread(target=thread_one)
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=thread_two)

# Start both threads
thread1.start()
thread2.start()

# Wait for both threads to complete
thread1.join()
thread2.join()

print("Both threads have completed.")
```

How to make sure my webdrive is thread safe

My new code for opening 5 browsers at the same time, is this thread safe?

```
import threading
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time 


# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
#                                Selenium set up                               #
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome('drivers\chromedriver.exe',options=chrome_options)


# Function to open a browser and perform actions
def open_browser_and_do_stuff(thread_num):
    # Initialize a new WebDriver instance for this thread
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('drivers\chromedriver.exe',options=chrome_options)

    try:
        # Perform actions with this WebDriver instance
        driver.get("https://whatismyipaddress.com/")
        time.sleep(20)
        search_box = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
        search_box.send_keys("Thread " + str(thread_num))
        search_box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    finally:
        # Ensure the WebDriver instance is properly closed
        driver.quit()

# Number of threads (browsers) to open
num_threads = 5

# Create and start threads
threads = []

for i in range(num_threads):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=open_browser_and_do_stuff, args=(i + 1,))
    threads.append(thread)
    thread.start()

# Wait for all threads to complete
for thread in threads:
    thread.join()

print("All threads have completed.")


# Wait for threads to complete
#thread1.join()
#thread2.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided in your first example is the correct way to create separate WebDriver instances for each thread.

```
import threading
from selenium import webdriver

def thread_function():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("https://www.example.com")
    driver.quit()

thread1 = threading.Thread(target=thread_function)
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=thread_function)
thread1.start()
thread2.start()
thread1.join()
thread2.join()
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, but for some reason the code only runs 1 browser at a time, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Thats ok. Selenium run for single browser at a time. You can run it on Chrome, Firefox separately . U just need to change in your code   driver = webdriver.Firefox()

Comment: Mahoob, what I was trying to do is running 5 chrome browsers separately at the same time using threads, you think this is not possible?

Comment: Mahoob, I am adding a new code at the moment, the code opens 5 chrome broswers at the same time, can you please give me your opinion on it if this is thread safe?

Comment: I have just added my new code, hope you can check it out <3

Comment: Yes you can run 5 chrome browsers at a time using multi-thread . As per your code you are creating two threads. So there will be 2 chrome browsers will run .